# Is Equal In Reverse Program

Tags: java, arrays, equals

This program will look at the elements in two arrays, then it will check if the first array is identical to the second array in reverse. It will return true if it is, and false if its not.

**Example:**

Array1 = {1,2,3,4,5}

Array2 = {5,4,3,2,1}

Output: *True*

**Example 2:**
Array1 = {1,2,3,4,5}

Array2 = {1,2,3,4,5}

Output: *False*

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int [] w = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int [] e = {5,4,3,2,1};

        System.out.println(isEqualInReverse(w,e));
    }
    public static boolean isEqualInReverse(int [  ] a, int [  ] b){
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
        for(int p = b.length - 1; p >= 0; p--)
        if (a[i] != b[p])
           return false;   
        }
    return true; 
    }

}
```

I've tried to implement this but do not get the expected result from my program. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You could also reverse the second array first. Collections.reverse() could help with that.

Answer (score 9):

You are nesting two for loops, so you compare every element in the first loop with every element in the second.

Instead you want a single loop and index from the end of 1.

i.e.

```
for (int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
   if (b[i] != a[a.length-1-i]) {
      return false;
   }
}
return true;
```

Really you should check that both arrays are the same length before entering this loop.

Comment: Should be `a.length - 1 - i`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Very true, good spot.

Comment: Why didn't my code work with the nested for loop?

Comment: @edwardlavaire Sit down with a pen and paper and work out step by step what each program is doing. The nested for loop is comparing every entry in one array with every entry in the other.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use one loop with index from the end of 1.

```
public static boolean isEqualInReverse(int [  ] a, int [  ] b){  
for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
       if (b[i] != a[a.length-1-i]) {
          return false;
       }
 }
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: Ok, can you explain why my code didn't work?